# Start X axis with a particular value rather than the one in data in HighCharts

Tags: date, highcharts

I have a `datetime` series in HighCharts which looks like this:

```
series: $.map(data, function (row) {
        return ({
            name: row[0],
            data: row[1],
        })
```

I want to start the date axis with a chosen value (10 September, 2012) rather than the one which the data provides (20 September, 2011). The date is basically the number of milliseconds from epoch Time. So, since I work in Scala, I calculate the seconds for 10 September, 2012 as

```
val foo = LocalDate.of(2012, 9, 10).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant.toEpochMilli
```

`foo` comes out to be `1347235200000`and I put this in my series like this:

```
series: $.map(data, function (row) {
        return ({
            name: row[0],
            data: row[1],
            pointStart: 1347235200000
        })
```

The X axis still starts with 20 September, 2011 rather than 10 September, 2012. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `row[1]` equal?  Does it have a datetime X value?  The documentation states that `pointStart` only works **if no x values are given for the points in a series**: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart

Comment: @Mark Yes, you are correct. row[1] has dates in the same (millisecond) format. So, What should I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Rather than the pointStart, set the x axis min to the value in question.  Yo may need to also set startOnTick to false for the axis.

Comment: You have two options, update your `row[1]` x values to use the dates you want.  Or remove the date portion from `row[1]` and use `pointStart` and `pointInterval` to auto generate them.